# Threejs - Draw a transparent texture with MeshDepthMaterial

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, transparency, depth-buffer

So I'm trying to have depth of field effect on some pixelart I made.

For that I need a texture with the depth information. So I render my texture on a plane using MeshDepthMaterial, but all I get is a grey rectangle, it completly ignores the alpha data in the texture (which is only 1 or 0, nothing inbetween).

Of course I'm using

```
depthMaterial.transparent = true;
depthMaterial.alphaTest = 0.5;
depthMaterial.needsUpdate = true; //just to be sure
```

Just for your interest this is my pixelart and how it is rendered: https://i.stack.imgur.com/udCwL.jpg

Answer (score 2):

`MeshDepthMaterial` does not read the surface texture at all.

Instead you would need to either override the value of the `'depth'` ShaderChunk to include UV's and your alpha-test-able texture, or add an extra `ShaderMaterial` to do the work yourself. Depending on the overall needs of your application, one approach would be better than the other. If no non-textured objects need to cast shadows, the former would be the simplest to maintain. If not, you'll need to do more work on managing which rendertargets get what and how.